# How to transfer a SIP call using the built in android SIP stack

Tags: android, sip

I am wondering how you can transfer a SIP call using the android SIP stack.

I have looked at liblinphone, and they have a method inside LinphoneCore named:
`transferCall(LinphoneCall call, String referTo)` (I have not tried using `liblinphone`, I have just taken a look at it), but I can't find anything similar in the `android.net.sip` API.

Any ideas?

Comment: This would be very useful. Did you get anywhere with it?

Comment: Sorry for an extremely late reply, but I have not been working anymore on this project, so I do not know. Hope anyone else is able to find a solution and share it with us.